# Pass arguments to new sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

Simple question: I want to be able to pass options into my sinatra app in config.ru. How is that possible? My config.ru looks like this:

```
run MyApp
```

But I want to have this in my MyApp class to take arguments:

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  def initialize(config)
    @config = config
  end
end
```

But I can't figure out a way to do this. Ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Use [set/settings](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html)

   ```
   require 'sinatra/base'

   class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
     get '/' do
       settings.time_at_startup.to_s
     end
   end

   # Just arbitrarily picking time as it'll be static but, diff for each run.
   MyApp.set :time_at_startup, Time.now

   run MyApp
   ```
2. Use a config file. See [Sinatra::ConfigFile](http://www.sinatrarb.com/contrib/config_file.html) in contrib (which also uses set and settings, but loads params from a YAML file)

Comment: So I can't have several versions of a single apps configured in different ways?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to configure with params, I figured out that you could do this:

```
require 'sinatra/base'

class AwesomeApp < Sinatra::Base
  def initialize(app = nil, params = {})
    super(app)
    @bootstrap = params.fetch(:bootstrap, false)
  end
end
```

Comment: In config.ru you'd use `run AwesomeApp.new(app, bootstrap: true)`. The reason you can either pass your class or an instance of your class is that `Sinatra::Base` comes with a class method `call` with essentially calls `new.call(env)`. https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1485

Answer (score 1):

[rnicholson's response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9657478) will be the best answer in most cases but if what you want is to have access to an instance variable in your routes, you can set these up using the `before` filter as explained in the [Sinatra README](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9657478):

> Before filters are evaluated before each request within the same context as the routes will be and can modify the request and response. Instance variables set in filters are accessible by routes and templates:
>
> ```
> before do
>   @note = 'Hi!'
>   request.path_info = '/foo/bar/baz'
> end
>
> get '/foo/*' do
>   @note #=> 'Hi!'
>   params['splat'] #=> 'bar/baz'
> end
> ```